# How can I get the Unicode codepoint represented by an integer in Swift?

Tags: swift, utf-8, utf8-decode

So I know how to convert String to utf8 format like this

```
for character in strings.utf8 {
     // for example A will converted to 65
     var utf8Value = character
}
```

I already read the guide but can't find how to convert Unicode code point that represented by integer to String. For example: converting 65 to A. I already tried to use the "\u"+utf8Value but it still failed.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you know, a single UTF8-byte is not always a character. In the case of 'A' it is, in the case of 'ñ' or 'ö' it is not... the question should be how to convert a unicode code point that is represented as an integer, into a Character...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that michael, I already edited my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the enum definition for `Character` you can see the following initializer:

```
init(_ scalar: UnicodeScalar)
```

If we then look at the struct UnicodeScalar, we see this initializer:

```
init(_ v: UInt32)
```

We can put them together, and we get a whole character

```
Character(UnicodeScalar(65))
```

and if we want it in a string, it's just another initializer away...

```
  1> String(Character(UnicodeScalar(65)))
$R1: String = "A"
```

Or (although I can't figure out why this one works) you can do

```
String(UnicodeScalar(65))
```

Comment: As for the last case: `String(UnicodeScalar(65))` used to work but would now be `String(describing: UnicodeScalar(65))`. This indicates that this particular initializer treats `UnicodeScalar` as `CustomStringConvertible`, asking for its self-`description` in the end.