# How to convert Unicode Character to Int in Swift

Tags: swift, unicode, integer

[A user asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284538/how-to-express-strings-in-swift-using-unicode-hexadecimal-values-utf-16/31284539?noredirect=1#comment64863749_31284539) the following question to [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31284539/3681880).

> I have a unicode character `\u{0D85}`. How do I get the `Int` value from it?

I was going to refer them to another Stack Overflow Q&A but I couldn't find one. These refer to converting the other direction:

- [How to convert an Int to a Character in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259425/how-to-convert-an-int-to-a-character-in-swift)
- [How can I get the Unicode codepoint represented by an integer in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24107868/how-can-i-get-the-unicode-codepoint-represented-by-an-integer-in-swift)

And these seem to be asking how to convert a number in string form to an actual `Int` (as in converting `"1"` to `1`).

- [Convert Character to Int in Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771119/convert-character-to-int-in-swift-2-0)
- [Convert Character to Int in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822429/convert-character-to-int-in-swift)

Rather than try to fit my answer in a comment to the asker, I am going to provide an answer below. The Type of `\u{0D85}` is somewhat unclear but I will cover the various possibilities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Hex to Int**

If you are starting with `\u{0D85}` and you know the hex value of the Unicode character, then you might as well write it in the following format because it is an `Int` already.

```
let myInt = 0x0D85                          // Int: 3461
```

**String to Int**

I assume, though, that you have `"\u{0D85}"` (in quotes), which makes it a `String` by default. And since it is a `String`, you can't be certain that you will only have a single `Int` value for the general case.

```
let myString = "\u{0D85}"

for element in myString.unicodeScalars {
    let myInt = element.value               // UInt32: 3461
}
```

I could have also used `myString.utf16` and `let myInt = Int(element)`, but I find it easier to deal with Unicode scalar values (UTF-32) when there is a possibility of things like emoji. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35193481/3681880) for more details.)

**Character to Int**

Swift `Character`, which is an [extended grapheme cluster](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID293), does not have a `utf16` or `unicodeScalars` property, so if you are starting with `Character` then convert it to a `String` first and then follow the directions in the **String to Int** section above.

```
let myChar: Character = "\u{0D85}"
let myString = String(myChar)
```

Comment: For `Int` to `Character` or `String` converstion, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31284539

Comment: Character now does have a `unicodeScalars` property. See Imanou Petit's answer for an example.

Answer (score 4):

With Swift 5, `Unicode.Scalar` has a [`value`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/2908540-value) property. `value` has the following declaration:

> A numeric representation of the Unicode scalar.

```
var value: UInt32 { get }
```

---

The following Playground sample codes show how to iterate over the `unicodeScalars` property of a `Character` or a `String` and print the `Int32` value of each Unicode scalar:

```
let char: Character = "\u{0D85}"

for scalar in char.unicodeScalars {
    print(scalar.value)
}

/*
 prints: 3461
 */
```

```
let str: String = "\u{0D85}"

for scalar in str.unicodeScalars {
    print(scalar.value)
}

/*
 prints: 3461
 */
```